# 1:1 table relation can't insert new row

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table inheritance in my database. I have table "`Item`" and Table "`Something`". `Item` has `ItemId` which is **primary key and auto increment**. In table `Something` I have `ItemId` which is **primary key (not autoincrement)**. Theese tables are in **1:1** relation.
So I have tried to insert data in those tables but this doesn't work:

```
...
DECLARE @itemId int

    INSERT INTO dbo.Items
    (ItemTypeId,UserId,CreatedOnDate,Title,Description)
    VALUES
    (@p_ItemTypeId,@p_UserId,@p_CreatedOnDate,@p_Title,@p_Description)

    SELECT @itemId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.Something
    (ItemsId)
    VALUES
    (@itemId)
...
```

This is the error that I get:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Items_Somethings".
```

Tables create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ItemdId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOnDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Somethings] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Somethings] ([ItemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Somethings]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Somethings](
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Somethings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: How it doesn't work? What error do you got? post it please.

Comment: I have added error to my question. When I try to insert some data to Items table it can't because it requires data in another table...

Comment: please show the definition FK_Items_Something

Comment: @1110 check the `@tiemId` coming from the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` print it using `SELECT @itemid`.

Comment: @Hogan how to get definition data? When I created relations I have just draw relation in database diagram (in management studio) between these two tables and select 'ItemId' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Somethings] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Somethings] ([ItemId])
```

Bad Direction of foreign key.

You should add foreign key to [dbo].[Somethings] and reference [dbo].[Items].ItemId
Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Somethings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Somethings_Items] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemId])
```

Answer (score 1):

In this script, you have inverted the inheritance between the tables. If `Something` table inherits from `Item` table then the `FK` has to be created at Table `Something' like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Somethings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Somethings_Items] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Somethings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Somethings_Items]
GO
```